# ошибки JS в консоли

Tags: jquery

Что означает, когда ошибки в консоли указывают на саму библиотеку jQuery?

```
jquery.js:1580 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
    at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery.js:1580)
    at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery.js:2232)
    at Sizzle.select (jquery.js:2659)
    at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery.js:884)
    at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2922)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:3032)
    at jQuery (jquery.js:98)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index:1136)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3583)
    at process (jquery.js:3651)
```

При этом страница абсолютно аналогична десятку других страниц, на которых подобных сообщений нет. Вкладки Sources и Network не дают возможности развернуть их, чтоб посмотреть стек. Ошибки вызываются кодом Gridview. Если его код убрать, то ошибки пропадают:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'class' => 'cab__table',
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
//            'id',
//            'event',
//            'whom',
//            'author',
            'text',
            //'ringing_id',
            [
                'attribute' => 'status',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'headerOptions' => ['style' => ['width' => '15%']],
                'value' => function($model){
                    return $model->statuses[$model->status];
                }
            ],

            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                'visibleButtons' => [
                    'view' => false,
                    'update' => false,
                    'delete' => true,
                ],

            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Код

```
$("#");
```

выдает в консоли ошибку такую же, как Ваша (включая последние несколько уровеней стека вызовов):

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
    at Function.oe.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at oe.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at oe.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.oe [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new w.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w (jquery.min.js:2)
    at window.onload ((index):32)
```

Таким образом, одна из Ваших переменных, которая становится значением `id`, - пустая.